# Trying to create a numeric 3.2.1 countdown with JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

```js
var readyGo = document.getElementById("readyGo");

setTimeout(three,1000);

function three(){
    var san = document.createElement("p");
    san.textContent = "three"
    san.className = "three nums";
    readyGo.appendChild(san);
}

setTimeout(two, 2000);

function two(){
    var ni = document.createElement("p");
    ni.textContent = "two";
    ni.className = "two nums";
    readyGo.appendChild(ni);
}

setTimeout(one, 3000);

function one(){
    var ichi = document.createElement("p");
    ichi.textContent = "one";
    ichi.className = "one nums";
    readyGo.appendChild(ichi);
}
```

```css
#readyGo {
    position:relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes count {
    0% {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

.nums {
    font-size:5rem;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.three {
    -webkit-animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
}

.two {
    -webkit-animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
}

.one {
    -webkit-animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
}
```

```html
 <div id="readyGo"></div>
```

Hi, I am trying to create a 3-2-1 countdown with JavaScript and CSS animation.
This will lead to starting a game. The newly created elements shown in the example are supposed to be **"img"** but I replaced with **"p"** elements so that it is visible. So the problem I have is I can't seemed to find a way to show one at a time or make each one replace one another every time the next one shows up. I tried visibility and display animations by placing them after "count" animations but I do not think I am supposed to do that? I feel like there is an easier or more productive way to achieve the result. Thank you for reading through the coding and my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are better of with an interval here, and you need to check to remove the previously created paragraph every time. I am using `shift` to pop the first remaining item in the array out of it, and then print it. The next time the function is called, it can repeat this pattern until its done:

```js
function countdown( parent, callback ){
  
  // This is the function we will call every 1000 ms using setInterval
  
  function count(){

    if( paragraph ){
      
      // Remove the paragraph if there is one
      paragraph.remove();

    }

    if( texts.length === 0 ){
      
      // If we ran out of text, use the callback to get started
      // Also, remove the interval
      // Also, return since we dont want this function to run anymore.
      clearInterval( interval );
      callback();
      return;

    }
  
    // Get the first item of the array out of the array.
    // Your array is now one item shorter.
    var text = texts.shift();
  
    // Create a paragraph to add to the DOM
    // This new paragraph will trigger an animation
    paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.textContent = text;
    paragraph.className = text + " nums";

    parent.appendChild( paragraph );

  }
  
  // These are all the text we want to display
  var texts = ['three', 'two', 'one'];
  
  // This will store the paragraph we are currently displaying
  var paragraph = null;
  
  // Initiate an interval, but store it in a variable so we can remove it later.
  var interval = setInterval( count, 1000 );

}

// Start a countdown by passing in the parentnode you want to use.
// Also add a callback, where you start your game.
countdown( document.getElementById("readyGo"), function(){
  
  document.getElementById("readyGo").innerHTML = '<p class="nums">start</p>';
  
});
```

```css
#readyGo {
    position:relative;
}

@keyframes count {
    0% { transform: scale(1.5); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}

.nums {

    font-size: 5rem;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    animation: count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="readyGo"></div>
```

Although we can fix your code by removing an existing paragraph as well, but it's at this point that the repetition of code becomes glaringly obvious, as all functions (`one`, `two` and `three`) become incredibly similar and repetitive, apart from the text content used:

```js
var readyGo = document.getElementById("readyGo");
var paragraph;

setTimeout(three,1000);

function three(){
    if( paragraph ){
      paragraph.remove();
    }
    paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.textContent = "three"
    paragraph.className = "three nums";
    readyGo.appendChild(paragraph);
}

setTimeout(two, 2000);

function two(){
    if( paragraph ){
      paragraph.remove();
    }
    paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.textContent = "two";
    paragraph.className = "two nums";
    readyGo.appendChild(paragraph);
}

setTimeout(one, 3000);

function one(){
    if( paragraph ){
      paragraph.remove();
    }
    paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.textContent = "one";
    paragraph.className = "one nums";
    readyGo.appendChild(paragraph);
}
```

```css
#readyGo {
    position:relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes count {
    0% {transform: scale(1.5);}
    100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

.nums {
    font-size:5rem;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.three {
    -webkit-animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
}

.two {
    -webkit-animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
}

.one {
    -webkit-animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
    animation:count 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,1,1) 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="readyGo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Codes were changed quite a bit so I have to take some time to understand despite your generous comments  :)

Comment: @yongjunjung Any questions, feel free to ask! Good luck!

Comment: So I converted paragraphs into images and it is working fine. Thanks again. What if I want to make the last image bigger with different animation ( image[3] )? I tried setting a new attribute (set Attribute) but it is not working.

Comment: @YongJunJung I guess you could just check if your array is length 1 and just add a different class if so? Something like ‘`paragraph.className = texts.lengt <= 1 ? ‘Three numslast’ : ‘three nums’`? (Sorry for typos, im on a phone)

Comment: Sorry I am not catching up here...so I assign a new class using images.length <= 1? then I do not get the next part. What I have so far is "Img.className = images.length == 3" (because I want the "Go" to be bigger). This is my array var images = ['imgs/3.svg', 'imgs/2.svg', 'imgs/1.svg','imgs/go.svg'];

Comment: @YongJunJung Your arrays `length` is being shortened every loop by one (using `shift`), so you want to wait until you have one item left (the `go` one, or `array.length === 1`) before you apply a class that has different CSS rules applied to it. **Note**: Actually you are waiting for when you pulled the last item of the array, so at that point your arrays `length` should be `0` as you have the last item in your variable, and no items in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does not make sense :( But I will try to make sense by digging in by myself for a few days...Cheers~

Comment: @YongJunJung Okay my bad, the last bit was actually confusing and turns out incorrect (its been a long day). Every time our `interval` calls the `count` function, we remove the first item (`string`) in the `array` and store it in a variable using `var text = texts.shift()`. This makes our `array.length` go down by one. So once our array length is `1` (_before_ we use `shift`, or `0`_after_, because of the reasons above that modify the `array`) we know we are in the last step of the loop and we can act accordingly by by adding a `class` or doing something entirely different.

Comment: Thank you again. This place is full of amazing and generous people. Unfortunately, I still don't know where to start..I understand the concept. is it like something like images[1].className = "name"?

Comment: @YongJunJung If you are using my code, the `shift()` should actually return an element. It literally removes the first element from the array and then returns it so that you can use it (and we store that returned element in `var text`), so if your array is empty after using `shift()`, then that means the last element is now stored inside `var text` and you can do whatever you want to it. I'd say read up on `shift()` on MDN (the _best) resource) - it isn't all that complicated.